# Delete button missing from Lightning Record page after creating from Classic page layout

Tags: salesforce-classic

Working in a Classic org that is (reluctantly) upgrading to Lightning.

- I created a Lightning Record page using as a starting point a page layout that had a Delete button
- Upon Save, the Lightning page had Edit, but no Delete
- Upgrading to dynamic actions had no effect

Where's my delete button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm so used to working in Lightning that I've forgotten the old tricks for conversion

- The button in question, `Delete` was actually overridden by a Visualforce page
- The button does not appear in the `Setup > Object Manager > Page Layout > Mobile and Lightning Experience actions`

and the reason for that is the Visualforce page was not marked as `Available for Lightning Experience, Experience Builder sites, and the mobile app`.

Easy fix by going to `Setup > Visualforce Pages > thepage` and ticking the box

[image]